# Lab device to periodically, automatically transfer zooplankton between containers

Tags: lab-techniques, limnology

I need a device to periodically draw a sample of transfer small aquatic organisms from one container to another without crushing/killing them.  Each sample would be on the order of 10ml.

My sketch of an idea is below.  It would use a pump to pull the sample from the source container into a reservoir through one check valve and pump it into the destination container through another.

I believe I can build it out of a peristaltic pump and commonly available check values, , but I'm worried that zooplankton won't fit through the values.

I'm also curious if there's a better and/or off-the-shelf solution for doing this kind of thing.

[image]

Comment: As if feeding predators in the second tank? Perhaps a "Fraction Collector".

Comment: There are multiple kinds of check valves such as ball valves.

Comment: @DKNguyen I've spent some time looking and I can't find any that useful for the small volumes I need other than those used in aquariums (which might work).  I'm new at this, so maybe I don't know which suppliers to check?  Any suggestions?

Comment: @PolypipeWrangler Yes, that's exactly what I'm doing.  The fraction collectors I see online don't look suitable.

Comment: Mcmaster Carr maybe?

Comment: If zooplankton are small, a dripping tap might work. Or in the predator tank have a screen (permeable to zooplankton only) and let them live there.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.